# How do i get ascii character from read?

Tags: c, ascii, memory-address

in this program, I need to store the frequency of the ascii characters i read in an array (in order to print the most frequent). the problem is that what i get from read is not ascii (most probably some kind of address) so in the buf[] array i get out of bounds.
Can anybody tell help me with that?

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<strings.h>

    #define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyAMA0"

    #define FALSE 0
    #define TRUE 1

    volatile int STOP=FALSE;

    int main()
    {
      int fd,c, res=0,i;
      struct termios oldtio,newtio;
      int buf[128] ;

      for (i=0;i<128;i++) buf[i]=0;

      fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
      if (fd <0) {perror(MODEMDEVICE); exit(-1); }

      tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
      while (STOP==FALSE) {     /* loop until we have a terminating condition */
            int r=read(fd,&c,1);
            write(1,&c,1);
            if (c=='\n') {
                    for(i=0;i<128;i++) 
                        if (res < buf[i] ) 
                            res = buf[i];
                    printf("first char %d \n", res);
            }
            else {
                    buf[c]++;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why are you doing this `int s = c;`?

Comment: sorry, i was experimenting and i kind of forgot it there. it has absolutely no reason to be there. thnx for noticing.

Comment: Please don't torture the reader with such oneliners, they don't make the code pryttier and particularily not more readable, also use more whitespace, the compiler will ignore them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int c` creates a variable of probably 4 bytes. It is not initialized, thus it may contain any garbage.

Then the system call

```
read(fd,&c,1)
```

changes one of these bytes, probably the highest or lowest, while leaving the others unchanged. Now you have a combination of 3 bytes of random garbage plus the one byte fresh from fd, placed somewhere in c.

And then you try to get sense out of that combination.

Things might work much better if you define c as `char`:

```
char c;
```

Comment: And also, please check the value of `r`, if it's `0` or `-1` you have to take special care.